# Integrate residential hardwired alarm zone with modern wireless sensor

Tags: relay, circuits

I have an old alarm system in my house that I would like to integrate with a modern system. The old system has hardwired circuits where multiple reed sensors in series monitor a zone with as many windows (A). The modern system has wireless contact sensors that use a reed switch to detect open/closed state (of a door or window). I thought if I could bypass the reed switch in the wireless sensor with the hardwired circuit, the wireless sensor would monitor the hardwired zone (B).

Some have tried this and results are inconsistent. One person states that the wireless sensor must be within 10 ft of the reed sensor in the house's circuit.

The circuit in my house is at least 100 feet long, has around 20 reed switches and I measured ~30 Ohm on it. The setup (B) does not work. I measured resistance on the reed switch in my wireless sensor (it is a [Ring "alarm contact sensor"](https://shop.ring.com/products/alarm-contact-sensor)) when it's closed and that's about 1 Ohm. The wireless sensor won’t detect open/close state changes of the house’s circuit, although upon wiring it up as in (B) it detects the initial state correctly.

Could I solve this situation by using the houses circuit as a low voltage control circuit for a relay that would open/close a circuit for the wireless sensor like in (C)?

[image]

Comment: If the only issues were those related to cable length, then activating some relay contact close to the IoT gizmo *might* work, though long term powering of relays in house wiring has its own issues to contemplate.  But the real problem here is that you are asking a *usage* question about a closed gizmo without *providing any relevant engineering specifications*.  Those are off topic here, because engineering methods cannot be applied.  You'd likely do best to pursue this with the company or on a user *forum*.

Comment: Please see this [Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446831) for a solution that seems to have worked for me to wire 5 windows sensors to 1 ring sensor.

Comment: @lcpr - thanks for the note! I added a new answer to this question to explain problem cause and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by induced voltage on the circuit. This can be seen by measuring voltage on the closed circuit. It is not much but it varies wildly and it is enough to confuse the wireless sensor.

The solution for me was to employ a [pull-up resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor) so the interference would not matter anymore. I implemented this with an Arduino and it is documented at this [Instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Integrate-Residential-Hardwired-Alarm-Zone-With-Mo/).

For your information, there is a DIY-alarm company that is offering a device to integrate existing hardwired alarm circuits with their solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably place an electromagnet near the wireless sensor's switch and use your loop of wired reed switches to switch the current through the electromagnet thus commanding the wireless sensor.

Comment: Sounds much simpler than what I thought, thank you!

Comment: yeah, the wireless sensor already contains half a relay, you just need to provide the other half,